# git log doesn't work with both the --graph option and the --since/--until options

Tags: git, git-log

I'm exploring a git repository (specifically, [Voldemort](https://github.com/voldemort/voldemort)).

When I run `git log` with the `--graph option`, I get some useful information:

```
computer:voldemort kevin$ git log --graph
* commit 3e16d366e6ae473153e7a1d99e62db96dc7b6c1b
| Author: Arunachalam Thirupathi <arunachalam.t@gmail.com>
| Date:   Thu Aug 28 15:48:01 2014 -0700
| 
|     Merge Read and Write Quota
|     
|     Combined GET and GETALL to GET
|     Combined PUT and DELETE to PUT
|     It would be cleaner if we rename the new GET to READ and PUT to WRITE
|     But it might break the backward compatibility so leaving it like this
|     for now.
|    
*   commit d5c048b3611ccac863b09f1c1433d0026748e77a
|\  Merge: c080cfc d7d7349
<!-- etc -->
```

When I run `git log` with the `--since` and `--until` options, it also works:

```
computer:voldemort kevin$ git log --since=2009-12-16 --until=2009-12-17
commit ae6983f377733153bd9c720019a4c72bafa7318a
Author: Alex Feinberg <alex@strlen.net>
Date:   Wed Dec 16 20:16:22 2009 -0800

    Rewriting the ec2 gossip test.

commit 6af8f35157f535a7cc27633599c635b96fe594e3
Merge: d4fdede 72ef048
Author: Alex Feinberg <alex@strlen.net>
Date:   Wed Dec 16 18:24:06 2009 -0800

    Merge branch 'rebalancing' of git://github.com/bbansal/voldemort into rebalancing
<!-- etc -->
```

However, when I run `git log` with all three options at once, I get no output:

```
computer:voldemort kevin$ git log --graph --since=2009-12-16 --until=2009-12-17
computer:voldemort kevin$
```

Switching the order the options appear in doesn't help:

```
computer:voldemort kevin$ git log --since=2009-12-16 --until=2009-12-17 --graph
computer:voldemort kevin$
```

How can I get this to work? The information depicted by the `--graph` option is what I really want to see - I want to be able to clearly tell when branches diverge and merge, so just looking over the data without the `--graph` option isn't suitable for me without a good replacement.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I'm using `git` on a MacBook running OS X 10.9.

Comment: Hm. I just tried this on a repository of my own, and it works for me (on a Linux box). So it's clearly not intentionally displaying nothing.

Comment: I just cloned `voldemort` (the repository, not the villain), and I can confirm the behaviour observed by Kevin. Trying to figure it out now...

Comment: Playing around with it some more, I found out that if I leave off the `--since` option and just use `--until`, it works. And since commits are listed with the most recent ones first, this is good enough for my task. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work with both date options...

Comment: @Jubobs: I haven't tried it myself but I'd look at the specific commits that show up without `--graph` and try the `--since/--until` sequence with `--topo-order`.  `--graph` forces topological sort; the date based selectors filter out by date; and perhaps the commits that would be retained, have the date orders crossing if the commit graph is handled in topo order instead of date order.  That's probably a bug in `git rev-list` if that's actually the case (throwing out too many commits)...

Comment: @torek `git log --since=2009-12-16 --until=2009-12-17 --graph --date-order` outputs nothing either.

Comment: @Jubobs: *adding* `--topo-order` to `--graph` should not change anything; what I was wondering was whether `--topo-order` without `--graph` suffices to get the empty set of revs.  In which case I think it's what I'm thinking of, `--since` and `--until` are too aggressive here.  I'm pretty sure the since/until stuff is assuming the internal list is in time-stamp order so they can throw out an entire chain based on one time-stamp compare.

Comment: @torek Sorry about the misunderstanding. `git log --since=2009-12-16 --until=2009-12-17 --topo-order` outputs nothing either.

Comment: @Jubobs anything happened with this. I'm getting the similar issues with --graph and --since. It will lose all the graph data

Comment: @Noctis IIRC, the tricky thing is that in order to produce output with `--graph`, Git sorts the commits topologically - this means that no commit in the output appears before any of its parent commits. If your date range happens to be at a point where some commits have a timestamp that actually comes before their parents' timestamps chronologically, the topological sort might quietly "filter" those commits out.